# create and assign a component to a vaadin grid column

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

Inside a for loop I use:

```
 Grid.Column<Record> nameColumn =  new Label(value);
           
 grid.addComponentColumn(item -> nameColumn).setHeader(strSelectColumnNames[c]);
           
          TextField firstNameField = new TextField();
           nameColumn.setEditorComponent(firstNameField);
```

but the first line is not correct. I need `nameColumn` in order to set the editor component.
How can I change the `new Label(value)`?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You should return a different component instance for each row.

```
grid.addComponentColumn(item -> new Label(value));
```

Usage example: https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/using-components